# Difference in behavior of 2 promises

Tags: promise, q

I would like to get rid of `q` library.
First snippet works, second does not.
Is there a difference between these 2 functions?

```js
this.removeAll = function (db) {
   var def = Q.defer();
   db.collection(collectionName).deleteMany({})
       .then(success => {
           def.resolve(success);
       }, error => {
           def.reject(error);
       })
   return def.promise
}
```

```js
this.removeAll = function (db) {

    return db.collection(collectionName).deleteMany({})
        .then(success => {
            resolve(success);
        }, error => {
            reject(error);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `resolve` and `reject` functions to call in your second snippet.

To avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), you should drop the entire `then` and `catch` calls:

```
this.removeAll = function (db) {
    return db.collection(collectionName).deleteMany({});
};
```